# How to nest configuration files within subdirectories (within /config/) in laravel version 5.2

Tags: laravel

I would like to call set config value under `/config/file.php`

Example:

```
Config('packages/configs/local/filename.organization.name')
```

[image: Folder Structure of Nested Config]

Please answer or give suggestion about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dot syntax works across directories as well.

Using the helper method:

E.g. `config('packages.configs.local.filename.organization.name')`